# How to push objects into arrays in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Ionic Framework and angularjs to develop one application. Here I am using checkbox inside ng-repeat. Using this I can able to insert checkbox checked values into array. But It is inserting like strings.

Like ["coding","testing"] .

But I want it like objects.

Like ["object","object"] . Inside that object values should be there.

Html code is

```
<div class="action-checkbox" ng-repeat="task in projecttasks">
      <h3>{{task.projectName}}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subtask in task.subTasks" ng-click="addprjtaskList(task,subtask)">
          <input id="{{subtask._id}}" name="{{subtask._id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{subtask.subTaskName}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(subtask.subTaskName) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(subtask.subTaskName)" class="hide"/>
          <label for="{{subtask._id}}" > 
            {{subtask.subTaskName}}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

controller code is

```
$scope.selection = [];
  // toggle selection for a given fruit by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(fruitName) {
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(fruitName);
      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
        console.log($scope.selection);
      }

      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(fruitName);
        console.log($scope.selection);
      }
    };
```

can anyone help me to do this..

Comment: Looks to me like you are pushing the name, not the object. Isn't the subtask  the object that you actually want?

Comment: $scope.selection.push(fruitName) will push a string value into selection array.  $scope.selection.push({ fruitName: fruitName}) will push an object with one property named fruitName with the string value in variable fruitName to the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `toggleSelection(fruitName)`
you are passing a string

then you are doing

```
$scope.selection.push(fruitName)
```

it is doing what it is told!

you need to pass the object to the function ...

```
ng-click="toggleSelection(subtask.subTaskName)"
```

SHOULD BE ...

```
ng-click="toggleSelection(subtask)"
```

AND THEN ...

push that instead!

Answer (score 2):

What I think you're looking for is to push `subtask` into an array, not `subtask.subTaskName`.

You'll have to change your view to `ng-click="toggleSelection(subtask)"` to reference the object instead of the object's name.

You'll also have to modify your `ng-checked="selection.indexOf(subtask.subTaskName) > -1` to reference a new function that checks for duplicity (since `indexOf()` doesn't like object arrays) .  I'll go into that further next.

Next, you'll have to update your controller to test for duplicates.  I suggest making a separate method using a for loop to iterate through your array, checking `subTaskName` for equality instead of `indexOf()`.  By making a separate method, you remove logic from your html, and allow code reuse.  A double win!

Then, you'll just have to push the object normally, and you're done!

Comment: duplicity == synonyms: deceitfulness, deceit, deception, double-dealing, underhandedness, dishonesty, fraud, fraudulence, sharp practice, chicanery, trickery, subterfuge, skulduggery, treachery  ;.)

Comment: Thanks George, but can't we agree that object comparisons can be very deceptive? :)